# I'm looking for material to understand a bit of transcendence of numbers and study whether they are rational or not

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I graduated at engineering and I know a fair amount of real analysis, calculus, etc. I read Apostol's book on analytic number theory.

I'm looking for some book to see a bit more about the theory on studying whether a number is o isn't rational. I'm not sure where to look though. I thought about p-adic theory, groups, rings, etc. And it made more confused.

Can you guys recommend me some material to study this area of math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ed Burger, [Exploring the Number Jungle](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/exploring-the-number-jungle-a-journey-into-diophantine-analysis), and [Making Transcendence Transparent](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/474462.Making_Transcendence_Transparent).